# strange bang(history bash expand)

Tags: linux, bash

In bash:

```
$ a=1
$ echo $a
1
$ echo "$a"
1
```

But:

```
$ echo !
!
$ echo "!"
bash: !: event not found
```

Why in "echo !", bash don't expand.

Comment: what were you expecting to happen ? the history would be "echo !!" (two exclamation marks)

Comment: @Sirex Why in `echo "!"` expand and `echo !` not expand?

Comment: What do you expect it to expand into?  As Sirex has said, for the last command, it's "!!", and as ooshro has said, a single "!" indicates to the shell that more will follow to inform the expansion.  Unless you give bash another character to say what you're trying to select from the history, it'll fail, as it is indeed failing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In "echo !", after bang followed the carriage return.

man bash

> `!` Start a history substitution, except when followed by a blank, newline, carriage return, = or ( (when the extglob shell  option is enabled using the shopt builtin).

Comment: why `echo -e "!\n"` and `echo -e "!\r"` expand?

Comment: @osdyng because after bang followed slash